Problem ordering writes using writeStream
I'm using node.js v22.6.0 on Windows 10. I'm trying to write a command that queries multiple sqlite3 tables and writes data to createWriteStream handle. The process is controlled by multiple functions where each queries, and formats data and then writes it.
The individual function are each doing there job correctly, but when I run all the functions in sequence, their respective data written does not end up in the file in the expected order!
I'm using the following patterns to structure the functions in the code:
function getEvents(refid, conn, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('getEvents: ' + refid);
    let sql = `select * from events where refid='${refid}' order by seq`;
    let results = '';
    conn.query(sql)
      .on('data', function (row) {
        // console.log(row);
        let tag = mapTag(row.ETYPE);
        let result = '1 ' + tag + '\n';
        if (row.DATE) result += '2 DATE ' + row.DATE + '\n';
        if (row.PLAC) result += '2 PLAC ' + row.PLAC + '\n';
        if (row.NOTE) result += '2 NOTE @' + row.NOTE + '@\n';
        results += result;
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('  end getEvents: ' + refid);
        resolve(res + results)
      })
      .on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
  });
}

function getFamc(refid, conn, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('getFamc: ' + refid);
    let sql = `select * from child where indi='${refid}' order by seq`;
    let result = '';
    conn.query(sql)
      .on('error', console.error)
      .on('data', function (row) {
        // console.log(row);
        result += '1 FAMC @' + row.FAMI + '@\n';
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log('  end getFamc: ' + refid);
        resolve( res + result );
      })
      .on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
  })
}

function outputIndi(conn, conn2, writer) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('outputIndi');
    let sql = 'select * from indi order by indi limit 5';
    conn.query(sql)
      .on('data', async function (row) {
        console.log('Fetching data for ' + row.INDI);
        let res = '0 @' + row.INDI + '@ INDI\n';
        res = await getEvents(row.INDI, conn2, res);
        res = await getFams(row.INDI, conn2, res);
        res = await getFamc(row.INDI, conn2, res);
        writer.write(res);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('  outputIndi done');
        resolve()
      })
      .on('error', (err) => console.error(err));
  })
}


async function main() {

  const writer = fs.createWriteStream( ged, { flags: 'w', encoding: 'utf8' } );
  writer.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(`An error occured while writing to the file. Error: ${error.message}`);
    reject();
  });
  writer.on('finish', () => {
    console.log(`All records have been written to ${ged}.`);
    writer.close();
    resolve();
  });
  console.log('writer created');

  let conn = anyDB.createConnection({
    adapter: 'sqlite3',
    database: dbfile
  });
  let conn2 = anyDB.createConnection({
    adapter: 'sqlite3',
    database: dbfile
  });

  await outputIndi(conn, conn2, writer);
  await outputFam(conn, conn2, writer);

}

main();


I haven't included all the code, but getFams() is similar to getFamc() and as I add more outputXXX() functions things get more mixed up in the resulting output file. So a logged the the calling sequence and get this:
ged:  test-out.ged
writer created
database conn and conn2 created
outputIndi
Fetching data for I0001
getEvents: I0001
Fetching data for I0002
getEvents: I0002
Fetching data for I0003
getEvents: I0003
Fetching data for I0004
getEvents: I0004
Fetching data for I0005
getEvents: I0005
  outputIndi done
outputFam
getEvents: F0001
getEvents: F0002
getEvents: F0003
getEvents: F0004
getEvents: F0005
  outputFam done
  end getEvents: I0001
getFams: I0001
  end getEvents: I0002
getFams: I0002
  end getEvents: I0003
getFams: I0003
  end getEvents: I0004
getFams: I0004
  end getEvents: I0005
getFams: I0005
  end getEvents: F0001
getChild: F0001
  end getEvents: F0002
getChild: F0002
  end getEvents: F0003
getChild: F0003
  end getEvents: F0004
getChild: F0004
  end getEvents: F0005
getChild: F0005
  end getFams: I0001
getFamc: I0001
  end getFams: I0002
getFamc: I0002
  end getFams: I0003
getFamc: I0003
  end getFams: I0004
getFamc: I0004
  end getFams: I0005
getFamc: I0005
  end getChild: F0001
  end getChild: F0002
  end getChild: F0003
  end getChild: F0004
  end getChild: F0005
  end getFamc: I0001
  end getFamc: I0002
  end getFamc: I0003
  end getFamc: I0004
  end getFamc: I0005


What I would expect is the outputIndi() would not end until all its sub functions have returned and written there data. I don't seem to be able to figure out the pattern to keep the program flow serialized in this asynchronous execution environment.
